# Delete Rows in Pandas DataFrame based on conditional expression

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
index        text        is_retweet
0            Test        False
1            RT bar      False
2            RT bazz     False
3            Test2       False
```

I want to delete the rows that begin with "RT"

I tried this:

```
my_df.drop(my_df.index[my_df['text'].find("RT") == 0], inplace = True)
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.startswith`:

```
new_df = df[~df["text"].str.startswith("RT")]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   index   text  is_retweet
0      0   Test       False
3      3  Test2       False
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option taking the position of characters:

```
df1 = df[df['text'].str[0:2] != 'RT']
df1
```

ouput:

```
    index   text    is_retweet
0       0   Test    False
3       3   Test2   False
```